# Laravel Gate custom response

Tags: laravel, authorization, policies

I have laravel 5.5 application and i use gates to authorise users. When the authorisation fails, the response is `This action is unauthorized` How can i overwrite this response? I want to offer users a custom response.

The way i implemented it is by defining  gates in AuthServiceProvider class and then using these gates with the middleware in my routes. In later laravel versions there is something like:

```
Gate::define('edit-settings', function ($user) {
    return $user->isAdmin
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny('You must be a super administrator.');
});
```

But allow and deny methods don't exist in Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [HandlesAuthorization](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization.php#L26) policy trait that handles custom messages, you can see that it throws a `AuthorizationException` with a custom message:

```
protected function deny($message = 'This action is unauthorized.')
{
    throw new AuthorizationException($message);
}
```

So you should be able to do the same in your guard, something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

Gate::define('edit-settings', function ($user) {
    if (! $user->isAdmin) {
        throw new AuthorizationException('You must be a super administrator.');
    }

    return true;
});
```